# Having negative value for non basic variable gives a non feasible solution in simplex method?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-algorithm

**Objective function =>** `x1 - 2x2`
Subject to =>

```
x2 <= 5
x1 - x2 >= 2
x1 ,x2, x3 >= 0
```

**Maximize?**

convert to standard form :
Maximize   -> `-x1 + 2x2`
Subject to ->

```
x2 <= 5
-x1 + x2 <= -2
```

convert to slack form :

```
Z = -x1 + 2x2
x3 = 5 - x2
x4 = -2 +x1 -x2
```

Basic solution (0,0,5,-2)

Can I found optimal solution in here? If not why?

Comment: If you don’t get an answer here you can try asking on the new [or.se] stack.

Comment: I published this question in **Operational Research** stack. For those who have the same question, [link to question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/having-negative-value-for-non-basic-variable-gives-a-infeasible-solution-in-simp)